# How to add bootstrap 3 to Angular2 webpack based project

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular, webpack

I have installed the npm packages for jquery & bootstrap, and then added imports into `vendor.ts`, but I still don't have any bootstrap styling showing up on the browser.

```
...
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.js'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';
...
```

I have also tried adding another entry within `webpack.common.js`, but that didn't help either.

```
entry: {
    'bootstrap': './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'main': './src/main.browser.ts'
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what is your webpack config?

Comment: Did you try to put the bootstrap in the `index.html` ?

Comment: @MarkoCen which part of the config do you want to see?

Comment: @JS_astronauts Yes, I know that will work. But i'm trying to do it using `vendor.js`.

Comment: the loaders part, did you add `exclude: /node_modules/` in your loader options?

Comment: I have an `exclude: /node_modules/` for `less` loader, but not for anything that's needed for Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 15):

You can just use one of the available angular seed projects.
For example this one https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack

to install bs, just run `npm install jquery bootstrap --save`

then add the following to `vendor.ts`

```
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

and add the following to `wepback.common.js`

```
plugins:[
    .....
    ..... ,
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({   
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery'
    })
]
```

For more details check 4th comment from the following link:
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/696

worked for me. I used to get complains about jquery not found but it solved my problem.

Comment: I've been looking for a simple solution and finally got one. Thank you so much for this!

Comment: For the js bootstrap to work I had to change the order of the ProvidePlugin elements to : [$: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery'].

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to tell to the Webpack entry point where to find the bootstrap file.

```
entry: {
    app: './app.ts',
    vendor: [
        'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
    ]
}
```

Comment: I've added my entry object into my question, can you tell me how your answer would work with what I have currently.